# Programatically searching the current site collection only

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise, object-model

I'm trying to programatically search a sharepoint site. The problem is, the results returned are from all site collections. How can I limit my search to only one site collection.

Here is how my code looks like

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query;

using (var siteColl = new SPSite(siteCollUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb site = siteColl.RootWeb)
            {
                KeywordQuery qRequest = new KeywordQuery(siteColl);

                qRequest.QueryText = strKeyword;
                qRequest.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;

                ResultTableCollection queryResults = qRequest.Execute();
                ResultTable queryResultsTable = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];
                DataTable queryDataTable = new DataTable();
                queryDataTable.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);

                qRequest.SelectProperties.Add("Title");

                var results = from queryResult in queryDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                              select new
                              {
                                  Title = queryResult.Field<string>("Title"),
                              };
                foreach (var v in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(v.Title);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the site collection url to your query text:

```
qRequest.QueryText = strKeyword + " site:\"{your-site-collection-url}\"";
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work for Root site collection? Even if I give web application Url in `site:"http://root-site-collection`, it still shows results from all site collections

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search a single site collection only, use `SPSiteDataQuery` and use `CAML` to build your search Query. You are now searching using the Farm wide Enterprise Search KeyWordQuery class, which will indeed include results from all site collections included in the Seach app's content sources.

```
SPSiteDataQuery qry = new SPSiteDataQuery();
qry.Query = 
  "<Where>" +
  "  <Eq>" + 
  "    <FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
  "    <Value Type='Text'>{WHATYOUARESEARCHFOR</Value>" +
  "  </Eq>" + 
  "<Where>";

site.GetData(qry);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPSiteDataQuery and you can use `SPSiteDataQuery.Webs` property to specify where the data will be retrieved from.

`"<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />"` : will search on all webs in the site collection

`"<Webs Scope='Recursive' />"` : will search the SPWeb on which you run GetSiteData and all subwebs

You can restrict the search using Lists and Query properties:

```
public void MySiteDataQuery()
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://YourSitecollectionURL"))
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
    {
      SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

       //query contacts list.
       query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='105' />";    
       query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />";

       query.Query = "<Where><Contains>" +
       "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='text'>John</Value>"+
        "</Contains></Where>";     
       query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";

       DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);


    }
  }
}
```